# JQuery getScript reporting error "is not a function" for a function that was not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, getscript

I am using JQuery's getScript function to load scripts depending on the device type, to hope fully save on unnecessary requests and load time for mobile devices. I have this code currently:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getScript('http://dev.imadeamerica.com/wp-content/themes/imadeamerica/js/mfc.js', function(){
        alert('It WORKED!');
    });
});
</script>
```

But it's not working, because I keep getting the error `$(window)._scrollable` is not a function. The only weird thing is that if you visit http://dev.imadeamerica.com/wp-content/themes/imadeamerica/js/mfc.js there is no call to that function. When I put a different script in the getScript function it works fine. But for some reason it thinks I am calling a function called `$(window)._scrollable` even though it's not present in that file.

I haven't found anything like this before and any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The first line of `setUp`, line 27, has this:

```
$(window)._scrollable();
```

So, yes, you are calling that function.

Answer (score 1):

open your script and @ line no 27 you have a call `$(window)._scrollable();` please define the function cz that functions is not defined

Comment: I am such an idiot. I kept searching for the string in the text, but I had the settings wrong on the search, so notepad++ didn't find it. Thank you for looking. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: its ok. no issues!if you find relevent answser please upvote them all. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Have the same issue when update bootstrap v4.0 to v4.3.1

Code example:

```
`https://codepen.io/pasha-oleynik/pen/yWvjaQ?editors=1011`
```

To fix need to use jquery without `slim` postfix. (use jquery-3.3.1.min.js instead of jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js)